# Getting an error when importing a module from a virtual environment in python

Tags: python, pip, kivy, virtualenv

I recently installed the Kivy library for python using `cmd` by pip method. I first created a virtual environment in some `"C:/User/Name/Kivy_venv"` location.
Then installed it there.
But when I type

> `import kivy`

in python shell, it returns an `error - > no module named 'Kivy'`.
So how can I import a module which is installed in a virtual environment?

Comment: did you activate the virtualenv? You might be missing some steps here. → **1)** create venv **2)** activate venv **3)** install kivy **4)** ??? **5)** profit

Comment: I did activated venv using "kivy_venv\Scripts\activate" command, before installing Kivy.

Comment: so how are you actually running your things? exact steps help

Comment: I am a beginner and might be missing something obvious. When I open a kivy example file using cmd(from virtual environment location) it works fine. But when I open python IDLE and import kivy there, it shows an error.

Comment: so that means that IDLE is not using the venv. I would suggest using either [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) as these are full-fledged IDE's which will make your life a lot easier. My personal preference is VS Code...